# How can I extract all text content from Photoshop with all associated styles for backgrounds? (see example inside)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, html

I have provided a lot of PSDs with lots of content to a coder. There were 50+ PSD and it took a team of 4 people 2 months to build them. Furthermore, the content was in Spanish and the coder doesn't speak the language. So talking to him I asked for an ETA and he told me "it will be quite fast, I already have the content extracted" which was really weird since I gave him the PSDs a couple hours before that.

So he sent me a page, and found this inside `pre` tags at the end of the file (just a short snippet, the file is like 10x bigger):

```
somethingsomething es una aplicación que reúne a amigos para que participen y apuiesten  en desafíos, generando una divertida interacción y una experiencia inmersiva que son claves en cualquier aplicación exitosa.
El negocio de somethingsomething es el ego. Se puede apostar sobre trend topics, alardear de las victorias en las redes y tener herramientas de alarde frente a oponentes.  

¡Asociate al éxito de somethingsomething!

¡Ser parte de esta startup es muy fácil! No hacen falta grandes inversiones, podés invertir cualquier cantidad con la que te sientas cómodo y tener un porcentaje de equities. ¡A mayor inversión, mayor porcentaje del negocio!

--------------------------------------------
bg (28,131,210)     #1c83d2

asdasdasdasdasdasdasdadsasdasdasd

¡Asociate a somethingsomething YA!
--------------------------------------------

bg (26,188,156)     #1abc9c | color overlay -> 60% black    |-> (10,75,62)      #0a4b3e
bg (26,188,156)     #1abc9c | color overlay -> 0% black     |-> (26,188,156)    #1abc9c
bg (26,188,156)     #1abc9c | color overlay -> 15% black    |-> (22,160,133)    #16a085
bg (26,188,156)     #1abc9c | color overlay -> 30% black    |-> (18,131,109)    #12836d
bg (26,188,156)     #1abc9c | color overlay -> 45% black    |-> (14,103,86)     #0e6756

¡Tu inversión hace que somethingsomething esté más cerca de hacerse realidad y generarte dividendos!

¡Asociate a somethingsomething YA!

--------------------------------------------
H -> (33,33,33)   #212121
p -> (51,51,51)   #333333
? -> (125,148,44) #7d942c
```

I'm aware of [Bramus](https://www.bram.us/2008/03/16/ps_bramustextexport-13-automatically-export-all-text-layers-from-photoshop-psd-to-a-text-file/) and [Omgmog](https://github.com/omgmog/photoshop-text-export) scripts, but never saw this kind of output. Unfortunately, almost immediately after this the programmer let us hanging and we no longer work together, so I can not ask him how he did it.

Any ideas on how to do this or what script did he use? I'm 90% certain he used Photoshop, but maybe he used something else

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the .psd source code reveals that text is stored like this.

`<photoshop:LayerText>CONTENT</photoshop:LayerText>`

So it needs just a bash script that performs a regex search across all files and writes the matches to a new file.

I'm for the most part designer – so no expert in this. But I think a good developer can do this reasonably quick.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure they used this. http://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/extract.html

this is nonsense to get the character count to submit my answer.

Comment: Instead of nonsense, could you explain a bit about what the link is and how it answers the question?

Comment: I don't think this is correct, please see the kind of output, I never got that by using the extracting assets in PS. If you mean the Dreamweaver option, I did check the video and it's not. This coder got an extremely different output, and it took him minutes (maybe seconds) for a really complex page, the video shows a lot of work for a very simple page, so I'm 100% sure it's not DW. This HAS to be an automated script